# Passing Sklearn model to a function to set arguments - type error: not callable?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
lr = LogisticRegression()

def logistic(model):
    
    test = model(random_state = 0)
    return test

logistic(lr)
```

I have the above code where I am trying to pass a logistic regression with no arguments and then doing so within the function.

I keep getting an error "TypeError: 'LogisticRegression' object is not callable"

Any idea why this is happening and how to resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

lr = LogisticRegression

def logistic(model):
    
    test = model(random_state = 0)
    return test

logistic(lr)
```